# Is $\{1/n : n = 1, 2, 3, ...\}$ metrizable with the subspace topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Topologize the sequence $\{1/n : n = 1, 2, 3, ...\}$ with the subspace topology. Can this be a metric space?

I tried assuming the Euclidean topology, but couldn't prove the triangle inequality $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| \leq |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{z}| + |\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{y}|$.

Is there any other metric that's easy to check for using the subspace topology?

Comment: Every subspace of a metric space is a metric space when we endow it with the restricted metric. Moreover, this metric on the subspace induces the subspace topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to restrict the usual metric. The inequality $$\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{z}\right| + \left|\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$$ is a given: to convince yourself of this, let $a = 1/x$, $b = 1/y$ and $c = 1/z$ and use $|a-b|\leq |a-c|+|c-b|$.